# Can someone explain why I'm getting 500 Internal Error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

1. I'm trying to plot a graph using a flask. But I'm getting 500 Internal Error when I'm trying to run on the server. My web page is visible but when I'm trying to select a dropdown to plot graph I'm getting the error. My console.log(url) is getting printed but I guess the ajax function is not getting executed.

.

```
'function get_map(url, rs, matrix, isScree, chart_title) {
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },

      success: function(result) {
        if(matrix) {
            console.log("in get_map 1")
            drawScatterPlotMatrix(result, rs, chart_title);
        } else {
            console.log("in get_map 2")
            drawScatter(result, rs, chart_title);
        }
        if(isScree) {
             console.log("in get_map")
             draw_scree_plot(result, chart_title)
        }
      },
      error: function(result) {
        $("#error").html(result);
      }
    });
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your Ajax request is being executed, as 500 is an HTTP error being returned by the server. If you watch the network tab in your browser's developer tools, you should see the request being made and the 500 being returned. Also, if you console log in the `error` portion of your Ajax request you should see the error that's being returned (in case your #error DOM element is not being rendered correctly).

So, the error is most likely something going wrong on the server. If your network response has no additional error information to help you, you might post a question with the server code handling the response. If it's a well established API, perhaps you could provide the URL.

Comment: I can see that after selecting the dropdown for which graph to plot there is no change in the url i.e. localhost:7777 and if it selects bar graph the link should be localhost:7777/bar but it's remaining as it is localhost:7777. I'm a beginner so kindly bare with me